# On devices with encryption enabled, can any apps start before the PIN is entered?

Tags: applications, encryption, disk-encryption

On devices with encryption enabled that require you to enter a PIN before the device finishes booting, can any apps (including built-in ones like chrome or gmail) start before the PIN is entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking of Android N, then the answer is **no**, which uses [File-based](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) encryption and the following are enabled

> AOSP Dialer (packages/apps/Dialer)
>
> Desk Clock (packages/apps/DeskClock)
>
> LatinIME (packages/inputmethods/LatinIME)*
>
> Settings App (packages/apps/Settings)*
>
> SystemUI (frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI)*
>
> - ***System** applications that use the `defaultToDeviceProtectedStorage` manifest attribute

Comment: Could Chrome start? And would I be correct in assuming, if it shows a PIN request before the lock-screen it's most likely using FDE, not FBE?

Comment: I wouldn't know about Chrome (haven't checked it's permissions) but it's unlikely. Second part - Android N is **mandated** to use FBE not FDE

Comment: I just checked -Chrome doesn't declare that permission , so it won't start